# Random generator that removes items from a list after picking

Tags: python, random

I have a list with 48 items. I want to randomly pick out 3 of those items, then remove those three items from the list. After that, randomly pick 3 new items. I wish to loop this 16 times until all the items are removed.

I've tried a for loop. But I can't figure out how to remove those specific items that was randomly selected from the list. I'm pretty new at both Python and programming. Help would be much appreciated.

```
list_ = ['Pink', 'Red', 'Green', 'Darkgreen', 'Blue', 'Skyblue'] * 8

loop_ = np.arange(0, 16)

for i in loop:
    print(random.sample(list_, 3))
```

Comment: Note, you shouldn't name your variables after python types, built ins etc

Comment: Not a good idea to use `list` as a name for a variable. You destroy the built-in function by the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method:

```
import numpy as np
import random

list = ['Pink', 'Red', 'Green', 'Darkgreen', 'Blue', 'Skyblue'] * 8

loop = np.arange(1,16)

for i in loop:
    item = random.sample(list, 3)
    print(item)
    for i in item:
        list.remove(i)
```

Note that is it considered a bad practice to name variables the names already given to built-ins, such as `list`. It would be better to name your list something else, for example, `colors`:

```
import random

colors = ['Pink', 'Red', 'Green', 'Darkgreen', 'Blue', 'Skyblue'] * 8

for i in range(0, len(colors), 3):
    item = random.sample(colors, 3)
    print(item)
    for i in item:
        colors.remove(i)
```

#### UPDATE

As pointed out nicely by @dawg, the `list.remove()` method always removes items from the list closest to the start of the list, taking away the concept of randomness.

I realized that it would be more accurate to use indices instead of values, so use `list.pop()` instead of `list.remove()`:

```
from random import randint

colors = ['Pink', 'Red', 'Green', 'Darkgreen', 'Blue', 'Skyblue'] * 8

while colors:
    lst = [colors.pop(randint(0, len(colors) - 1)) for _ in range(3)]
    print(lst)
```

Comment: Since the OP has a smaller list multiplied to make a bigger list, the `.remove` method likely is removing a different item than the one sampled. It really should be done by index with `del`

Comment: Also `np.arange(1,16)` is of 15 length

Comment: @dawg Hey, thank you! Yeah, it was my fault that I made the grave error, sorry about that.

Comment: @IoaTzimas You're right, thanks :) But I believe it was a minor error on the OP's code.

Comment: @Ann Zen, thanks! One question. What do the undersore do in ”for _ in range(3)?

Comment: @Henrik When the values of an iterable won't be used in the loop, using an underscore is more efficient than assigning each value of the iterable, like `i`, to a variable.

Comment: @Ann Zen - so the expression - colors.pop(randint(0 - len(colors) - )) - runs three times, is that what the underscore does in a for loop applied like above?

Comment: @Ann Zen And a while loop runs until colors are empty. I don't follow entirely why you withdraw 1 from( 0 - len(col))? :)

Comment: @Henrik The last index of an array is always the length of the array, minus `1`. So the indices of `[8, 4, 0]` is `0, 1, 2` *(`2` is the length of the list minus `1`)*. `while colors` means keep iterating through until `colors` empties out.

Answer (score 2):

`np.arange(1,16)` is of 15 length, but you want to loop 16 times. Also, avoide using list.remove when there are duplicates in the list, even though probably it will not cause troubles in your specific problem. Finally, as said, avoid using 'list' as name as it's already used by Python.
Here is my suggestion, working on indexes and using list.pop(0) method:

```
l = ['Pink', 'Red', 'Green', 'Darkgreen', 'Blue', 'Skyblue'] * 8

for i in range(16):
    item = random.sample(range(len(l)), 3)
    for k in sorted(item, reverse=True):
        l.pop(k)

print(l)
#[]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do the list.pop(index) method.

```py
import random as rd
import numpy as np
lst = ['Pink', 'Red', 'Green', 'Darkgreen', 'Blue', 'Skyblue'] * 8
loop = np.arange(1,16)
for i in loop:
    for k in range(0,3):
        item = lst.pop(rd.choice(range(0,len(lst))))
        print(item)
```

.pop(index) method does two things. It returns the element at the given index of a list. It then removes that element from the list.

Inside of the .pop() function we have the following: a random choice of a number (which is the index) the choice is a list of numbers between 0 and the length of the list (exclusive).

Comment: np.arange(1,16) is of 15 length

Comment: im just going off of what the original poster had in theirs to keep is as simple as possible. Dont tell me its length 15, tell the OP that it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

my_list = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
    33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48
]

for i in range(16):
    removed_list = random.sample(my_list, 3)
    for item in removed_list:
        my_list.remove(item)
        
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753893/random-genereator-that-removes-items-from-a-list-after-picking/65753913?noredirect=1#comment116256782_65753913) comment by dawg.